# how to clear the entry box when it's active(clicked)

Tags: c, linux, gtk3

I wanted to clear my entrybox in order to when I want to enter something again it's clear.
I implemented a Simple Webbrowser.
In the entrybox is always the url but what I was looking for is that if i click (activate) the entrybox, the entrybox should be cleared.

I hopped I could do something like this:

```
if(gtk_window_get_focus(GTK_WINDOW(w->window)) == w->entry)
          gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY(w->entry), "");
```

But I don't realy know where to do it and how this wokrs that it can detect that the entrybock was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing Alexander's answer ...

In case you don't know to associate callbacks with signals, you can use [`g_signal_connect()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect). This takes four parameters:

1. the object we are interested in - we need to use `G_OBJECT()` to cast this to the relevant type
2. the signal we want to watch - in this case `grab-focus`
3. the *callback* to invoke when the signal is raised
4. arbitrary user data (probably not needed in this case).

In this case you could call it like

```c
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(w->entry), "grab-focus", G_CALLBACK(on_input_focus), NULL);
```

If you check the signature of the the callback for the [`grab-focus` signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-grab-focus) you will see it accepts two arguments and returns nothing. The last argument is the arbitrary user data which was the last parameter in the `g_signal_connect()` function; we did not set it and can ignore it. The first argument is the widget on which the signal was triggered - which we can cast to a `GtkEntry`.

```c
void on_input_focus(GtkWidget *w, gpointer data) {
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(w), "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways, but before we start: user may want to copy URL, clearing it on click event may be confusing.

1. Connect to parent class `"grab-focus"` signal
2. Use `gtk_entry_set_placeholder_text` to make text a placeholder (appears as slightly shadowed)
3. Conforming to the note above: set a secondary icon (`gtk_entry_set_icon_from_icon_name`, icon "edit-clear-symbolic") and connect to `"icon_press"` signal.